# Multiple KARAF servers using same keystore.jks

Tags: java, ssl, https, keystore, karaf

We have KARAF server running in 2 different machines. Server A is hosting some modules in X machine and server B hosting some modules in Y machine. We are generating keystore.jks and copying to server A and B. Some modules in server A makes https request to some modules in server B and viceversa (modules in server B also makes https request to modules in server A).

We are just copying keystore.jks on both the servers running in different machine and we are able to communicate. Could you please let us know if this approach is fine.

Thanks

Comment: Whether this is "fine" depends on your security requirements.

Comment: We want to know whether there is an alternate approach to resolve handshake and communicate between 2 servers.